# Circular ImageView background is actually square and not circular?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a question regarding a circular `ImageView`. When I try to set the background color of my `ImageView`, it actually ends up being a square and not a circle when in reality I would want the `ImageView` to be a simple circular `ImageView` with some text as the image. Here was my attempt.

```
ImageView imageView = postViewHolder.fourthCommenter;
Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(30, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(b,  Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setShader(shader);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
c.drawCircle(b.getWidth()/2, b.getHeight()/2, b.getWidth()/2, paint);
c.drawText("+10",30,30,paint);
imageView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.material_color_grey_200));
imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

All I want is to have the image show a grey circular `Imageview` with the word "+10" in it. What shows up is a simple square `Imageview` with no text in it. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be apprecaited.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is an example of what I would want. I want to have an image that looks exactly like the `+16` image shown on this photo:

[image]

Comment: you called `setBackgroundColor`, thats why yout `ImageView` has its background filled with that color

Comment: @pskink but I want the `ImageView` to have a background that is circular, not square, and filled with that color.

Comment: so do not call `setBackgroundColor`

Comment: @pskink but then how can I set the background color of my `ImageView`? What if I want to change it to a green or blue color?

Comment: i have no idea what you want... do you want to have solid, square background color or not?

Comment: @pskink I have posted an image on my original post showing what I want. It is the image at the right that says `+16`

Comment: so you dont need any `setBackgroundColor`, just read `View#setBackgroundColor` documentation

Comment: @pskink if I don't need `setBackgroundColor`, then what would I need to change the color of the `ImageView`? I posted my attempt above.

Comment: read `Paint` documentation then

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the proper way to do it , but it should work for your case :

First use this to create the bitmap with the required circle shape :

```
public Bitmap getCircledBmp(Context mContext,Bitmap bmp){

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.material_color_grey_200);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        RectF rectFloat = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(color);


        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawOval(rectFloat, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return bmp;

    }
```

Then add the text that you want :

```
public Bitmap drawText(String text, Bitmap bmp, int textSize) {

    //text dimensions

    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint,
            bmp.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

    //draw text
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate((canvas.getWidth() / 2), (canvas.getHeight() / 2) -
            ((mTextLayout.getHeight() / 2)));
    mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    return bmp;
}
```

In the end you should get your desired image like this :

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //change the values whatever you like
ImageView imageView = postViewHolder.fourthCommenter;
imageview.setImageBitmap(drawText("+10",getCircledBmp(this,bmp),30));
```

Answer (score 0):

> All I want is to have the image show a grey circular Imageview

Try this code

```
Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.add_image);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePicture);
imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedBitmap(picture));

 public Bitmap getRoundedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
        c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
        return circleBitmap;
    }
```

**Your xml file**

```
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/light_gray" />
```

and add this in **build.gradle**

```
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

**Cirular `ImageView` Done !**

[image]